# time value 00:00.0 and 30:00.0 and its missing the 12 in front of the time value?

Tags: python, pandas

This is my code, but I get an error saying:

> DateParseError: hour must be in 0..23.

How do I get just the minutes to show on my code?

```
Interval     kWh/hh
30:00.0      1.053
00:00.0      0.862
30:00.0      1.637
00:00.0      2.052

#convert time to just minutes
time_strs = ['30:00.0', '00:00.0']
pis = pd.PeriodIndex(time_strs, freq='M')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add in the hours (which would be zero). Also you have used 'M' as the frequency but 'M' means months - you need to use 'T' (or 'minute').

```
time_strs = ['00:30:00.0','00:00:00.0']
pis = pd.PeriodIndex(time_strs, freq='minute')
```

I'm not too sure what it is you are trying to do but hopefully this helps resolve your current issue!

Comment: In `0.20.3`, `freq='T'` works but `'minute'` throws an error: `ValueError: Invalid frequency: minute`.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but if you want to convert the time in your Interval column to minutes I would do this. I'm assuming its H:M.S.

```
def to_minutes(x):
    x = [int(y) for y in x]
    minutes = x[0]*60 + x[1] + x[2]/60
    return minutes

df['Interval_Minutes'] = df['Interval'].str.split(r'[:.]').apply(to_minutes)
```